# Sending mail to customer and admin at the same time preferably using different templates

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

In my module I have a feature that adds custom tab to product and there is a form that accepts name, mail and question

I need to send mail both to admin and customer.

This is my mail helper

```
<?php

namespace Alex\AskQuestion\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\User\Model\UserFactory;

class Mail extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    private $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var UserFactory
     */
    private $userFactory;

    /**
     * Mail constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param UserFactory $userFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context               $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        TransportBuilder      $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface        $inlineTranslation,
        ScopeConfigInterface  $scopeConfig,
        UserFactory           $userFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @param $customerEmail
     * @param string $customerName
     * @param string $message
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws MailException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function sendMail($customerEmail, string $customerName, string $message)
    {
        $templateOptions = [
            'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        ];
        $templateVars = [
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'customer_name' => $customerName,
            'message' => $message
        ];

        $from = ['email' => $customerEmail, 'name' => $customerName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        // Send email to admin
        $toAdmin = [$this->getAdminEmail()];
        $transportAdmin = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('askquestion_options_email_settings_template_settings_admin')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFromByScope($from)
            ->addTo($toAdmin)
            ->getTransport();
        $transportAdmin->sendMessage();

        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    private function getAdminEmail()
    {
        $transEmailSeller = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        if ($transEmailSeller) {
            return $transEmailSeller;
        }
        
        return '';
    }
}
```

Code from submit index

```
/**
             * Send Email
             */
            if ($request->getParam('email')) {
                $email = $request->getParam('email');
                $customerName = $request->getParam('name');
                $message = $request->getParam('question');

                $this->mailHelper->sendMail($email, $customerName, $message);
            }
```

Comment: Is there any issue you are facing?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transportBuilder class.

\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder

```
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars((array('data' => $parseDataVars)))
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->addTo($addto)
                    ->addCc($addCc)
                    ->addBcc($addBcc)
                    ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($file))
                    ->getTransport();

                 $transport->sendMessage();
```

- With "addTo" and "addCc" you can add the admin and the customer mail.
- With "setTemplateIdentifier" you can set the template ID.